# How to convert syntaxt of query from mysql to sqlite3

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlite

I have the following query executed using pandas' `read_sql` method that works great when querying against a MySQL db:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM semantic_groups sg join semantic_types st on sg.tui = st.tui where group_name in ({})".format(', '.join(['%s' for _ in semtypes]))  

stypes = pd.read_sql(sql, params=[semtypes], con=engine)
```

However, when I run this against the same tables in a sqlite3 file, I get and error that:

```
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM semantic_groups sg join semantic_types st on sg.tui = st.tui where group_name in (%s)': near "%": syntax error
```

Good and fine, so I replace the `%s` with a `?`, which, according to everything I've seen, should work, but I get the error:

```
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT st.tui, abbreviation, clamp_name, ctakes_name FROM semantic_groups sg join semantic_types st on sg.tui = st.tui where group_name in (?)': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The parameter being passed, `semtypes`, is just a list of string values (`['Anatomy']` for testing purposes), and `group_name` is a `TEXT` field, so I'm not sure what this error means?

Comment: Probably that should be `params=semtypes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that should be `params=semtypes`?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM semantic_groups sg join semantic_types st on sg.tui = st.tui where group_name in ({})".format(', '.join(['?' for _ in semtypes]))  

stypes = pd.read_sql(sql, params=semtypes, con=engine)
```

Comment: By jove! So simple! Thanks! This was driving me nuts.